# expectation of effective sample size

Tags: probability

I have been given $P(X=k) = \frac {{N \choose k} \Delta ^ k O^n} {N^n}$, k = 1,...,N
I have to find $E(X(X-1))$.

Now,

$$E((N-X)(N-X-1)) = N(N-1)(1 - \frac {2} {N})^n.$$

Then

$$E(X(X+1)) =  N(N-1)(1 - \frac {2} {N})^n  - N(N-1) + 2N^2(1-\frac{1}{N})^n.$$
$$E(X(X-1 +2))=E(X(X-1)+2X) = N(N-1)(1 - \frac {2} {N})^n  - N(N-1) + 2N^2(1-\frac{1}{N})^n$$
$$E(X(X-1)) = N(N-1)(1 - \frac {2} {N})^n  - N(N-1) + 2N^2(1-\frac{1}{N})^n$$
$$E(X(X-1)) = N(N-1)[(1 - \frac {2} {N})^n  -1 + 2(1-\frac{1}{N})^n]$$

What I should get is:

$$E(X(X-1)) = N(N-1)[1 + (1 - \frac {2} {N})^n  - 2(1-\frac{1}{N})^n]$$

Where am I going wrong?